# Kivy - I can't see the picture

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am developing a mobile application. There should be a picture in the introduction of my application. Even though I put the picture and show the way, the picture does not appear when I run the application. It is replaced by a white screen. How can I solve it?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation, AnimationTransition

class loginImage(Image):
   pass

class loginScreen(App):
   def build(self):
       img = Image()
       return img

loginScreen().run()
```

My .kv code in here:

```
<-loginScreen>:
source: 'images.jpeg'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kv rules are for widgets, not the App class, so your source isn't applied to anything.

Set the source of the Image widget that you return.